# Not display an image of category of custom post

Tags: posts, customization

```
$cats = array('taxonomy'=>'types');

$categories = get_categories($cats);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category:'. $category->name.' </p> <br>';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p> <br>';
    $term_id = $category->term_id;
    echo $term_id;
    $meta_image = wp_get_attachment_image($category->$term_id); 
    echo $meta_image; 
    ?>
       <img src="<?=$meta_image?>" alt="image">
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `$category->$term_id` is wrong use `$category->term_id`

I don't think `$category->$term_id` will give you the desired result

For this you must have create some meta for the image in the backend.

```
term_image_id = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'your-term-id', true );
```

Here the term id is `$category->term_id` and the term value is `your-term-id`

Can you please check if that works or not?